# Iterate over agent's parameters

Tags: java, loops, parameters, agent, anylogic

I'm creating an agent based on another by code. The original agent is in a delay block being processed and I want to create copies where only the id will change and execute the method take in an Enter block.

In order to copy information from the original agent I can't seem to find a better way than to specify each parameter as in:

```
newAgent.color = original.color;
newAgent.component = original.component;
newAgent.geometry = original.geometry;
...
newAgent.LastParameter = original.LastParameter;
```

and so on.

Is there a way to iterate over an agent parameters to improve this action?

Thank you in advance,
Luís

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem and I'm posting the answer as other people might face it in the future. It's something simple that I had already tried but with a type casting problem.

The code structure is as follows:

```
add_myAgents();
for(String p : agent.getParameterNames())
{
    myAgents.get(myAgents.size()-1).setParameter(p, agent.getParameter(p), true);
}
enter.take(myAgents.get(myAgents.size()-1));
```

I found that using `myAgent prod = new MyAgent()` did not work. The duplicate must be inserted in a population so I created an intially empty population called ***myAgents*** and there's where I add the duplicate.